# Column Summary Links don't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365, site-column, hyperlink

i need to insert multiple links in my list item and i have seen that exists a type of site column named "Summary Links".
This column works in edit, allowing me to add multiple links and groups.

[image]

the links are not showed in "view" and in list view.

I'm working on sharepoint online and i've enabled the publishing feature.

[image]

Someone has any idea? thanks in advance

Comment: I've solved using multiline and inserting a content webpart with a javascript that perform a parsing for the value in multiline field. The data are presented with javascript that delete the predefined column and append at the table a customized div.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the description of the Summary Links Column is as follows:

```
Summary Links is a site column created by the Publishing feature. It is used on the Welcome Page Content Type to display a set of links.
```

maybe this answers your question. 
My Suggestion is:

- Use Summary Links Web Part (Under Content Rollup)

OR

- Use Multi line of text column (choose option: Enhanced rich text (Rich text with pictures, tables, and hyperlinks)

Comment: i've created a new site column of type "SummaryLinks" associated to my own content type, but this is not showed on the list that had it.
The XML of my Field is: 
`<Field 
 Type="SummaryLinks" 
 DisplayName="References" 
 RichText="TRUE" 
 RichTextMode="FullHtml" 
 Required="FALSE" 
 Group="EPS columns" 
 ID="{b04c141d-d431-475c-a431-3baadf3850d6}" 
 SourceID="{808973f7-6c59-4448-960e-d5143edd4599}" 
 StaticName="References" 
 Name="References" 
 Version="1" 
 Customization="" 
 AllowDeletion="TRUE"/>` I can't use webpart because every item has it own links

Comment: I dont think this will work unless your content type is associated with a page layout where you can place your column and it will render as an HTML!

Comment: the strange thing is that in edit i can see links, but in view the field is empty. Here there are some links to images that can explain my situation:

On view
[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/5e08fb0.jpg)
[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/5ea2cd8.jpg)

On edit
[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/a6c3971.jpg)
[link](https://i.imgsafe.org/a76afce.jpg)

Comment: Try to use the multi line of text (as I mentioned on my answer) and see if this fulfills your reqs.

Good Luck!

Comment: I would have preferred use summary links because is more user frendly, columns were populated by user, but for that i think than javascript can help! :D thanks for all!